# How to cast utc date to GMT +8 in Presto SQL?

Tags: presto

Would like to check how to convert utc time to GMT +8 timezone in Presto sql?

http://teradata.github.io/presto/docs/127t/functions/datetime.html suggests using current_timezone but I am not sure how.

Comment: What form (data type) is "utc time" in? Is it eg  `bigint` data type with number of seconds or `timestamp` data type that should be interpreted in UTC?

Comment: Anyway, we have [`at_timezone()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#at_timezone) function for this purpose.